# Why can my query not locate the RowNum column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query to get results in a paging manner. However, when I tried to execute it I get errors like `Invalid column name 'RowNum'`

```
DECLARE @PageNum AS INT;
DECLARE @PageSize AS INT;
SET @PageNum = 2;
SET @PageSize = 10;
WITH videosrn AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY videoid) AS RowNum
          ,videoid
          ,title
      FROM videos
)
SELECT *   FROM videos
 WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize
 ORDER BY videoid
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need  `select * from videosrn` (not `videos`)

Answer (score 1):

RowNum is an implicit calculated column in Oracle. Use a different name.

Comment: no actually i'm trying to execute in sql server. any how i changed it to rownum1 but still i'm getting the same problem